# Networking not working after creating VM from snapshot - GCE

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-compute-engine

Having troubles with network configuration after creating a new Ubuntu (18.04.2) VM from snapshot on GCE.

After I start the VM, I can see in the GCE console that the new VM has an internal and external IP assigned. After serial-ing into the VM, I can see two network interfaces, lo and ens4. Lo is up and running and ens4 is down.

I compared the config in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml to a working VM and they are identical.

I tried resetting the network interfaces and restarting the Vm.

Any suggestions on this? I'll be happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured this one out. You can serial into the VM and type in `sudo dhclient` and it will pull a new IP and work as expected after that